# nextjs frontend with nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, next.js

I have nextjs with the content as the following on `server/server.js` where it proxy to node.js, where the entry file is `server.js` on node.js.
nextjs and node.js are separated code base currently.

```
import express from 'express';
import proxy from 'express-http-proxy';
import next from 'next';

import helmet from 'helmet';

const app = next({ dev: false });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();
    const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;

    server.use(helmet());
    server.use('/api', proxy(API_URL, {
        proxyReqPathResolver: (req) => req.originalUrl,
        limit: '50mb'
    }));
    server.use('/files', proxy(API_URL, {
        proxyReqPathResolver: (req) => req.originalUrl,
        limit: '50mb'
    }));
    server.use('/images', proxy(API_URL, {
        proxyReqPathResolver: (req) => req.originalUrl,
        limit: '50mb'
    }));
    server.use('/.well-known', proxy(API_URL, {
        proxyReqPathResolver: (req) => req.originalUrl,
        limit: '50mb'
    }));

    server.all('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res);
    });
    server.listen(80, err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('> Ready on port 80');
    });
});
```

If I want to merge the node.js code with next.js, is it sufficient to replace all files from node.js server into the server folder of next.js? Is server folder in next.js visible from client that calls it?

Comment: The [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) code is not visible to the client. Have you tried using that code in your Next.js app? Have you encountered any issues?